# I tried to install Linux with a hybrid single boot partition and now I can’t reinstall Windows

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-10, hybrid

I tried to install Linux on SSD and HHD, but I think I accidentally got rid of everything. I have been trying to use an 8 GB usb to reinstall windows but it hasn’t been working. With Ventoy I am able to get the Install or repair windows page, but when I go to install it says it is missing a file. With UNetBootin, I get stuck in an infinite loop with automatic boot. Is my only option to try to do Windows Creation tool on another computer? I am not sure what’s going on.

I am on my phone right now, but I can try to get photos later on.

edit: i figured it out

Comment: WoeUSB works if the stick is previously formatted as NTFS. MKUSB just works. But yes, if you have access to a Windows machine use the official tool.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012, so most hardware is now UEFI, but if you installed Ubunt in BIOS/MBR configuration, you just about have to install Windows in BIOS mode. Newer Windows has .wim file over 4GB, so many older instructions are incorrect as for UEFI install you have to use FAT32 and cannot just copy files to FAT32 flash drive. Windows creation tools splits .wim to make it work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)